Why does my function terminate prematuraly when I incorporate str.lower()?
I'm new to Python and I've include my function below that takes a user entered phrase and then finds the first instance of a given character. It works as intended, however I've been trying to figure out a way to include ".lower()" into the code so that it doesn't count capital and lowercase letters as separate characters. For example, if you want to find the first instance of s in "Scissor" I want it to return 0 instead of 3.
Any and all help would be much appreciated.
def findCharacter(list, position, char):
    if position < 0:
        position = 0
    if position == len(list):
        return None
    if list[position] is char:
        print("The letter", char, "is located at the position:", position)
    else:
        return findCharacter(list, position + 1, char)

phrase = input("Enter a phrase: ")
#phrase = phrase.lower()
letter = input("enter the letter in the phrase to find: ")
#letter = letter.lower()

findCharacter(phrase, 0, letter)

I've tried attaching ".lower()" within the function, outside of the function. I've tried attaching it to the inputs themselves and whenever/wherever I incorporate ".lower()" the function just terminates prematurely before giving the character's position within the string.

if list[position] is char: is wrong. Specifically, is is for identity testing (true only if the two objects are the same object), and while it will work on some versions of Python, for some characters, it will be wrong anytime a single character is not an implementation-defined singleton. You want if list[position] == char:. Also, it's a bad idea to name a variable list; it means you can't use the list constructor for the entire scope in which the variable exists. Just use lst or seq and avoid the potential gotcha.

Building on what @ShadowRanger said, I'd hazard a guess that is might be "accidentally" working without the .lower() due to string interning or something, but since calling lower() will construct a new str object it breaks whatever was allowing the code to work.  But that's less important than the core point that you should not expect or depend on is working to determine whether two strings/characters are identical.

Can you give specific information on where .lower() failed? It should work just fine (modulo the mistake with is) if you call it as findCharacter(phrase.lower(), 0, letter.lower()). Or begin the function with list = list.lower() (a very weird line, but you gave a value that is logically a string the name list) and char = char.lower(). Your code should work just fine uncommenting those two commented lines though.

You have not said exactly what the problem is.  What does "terminate prematurely" mean?  Do you mean the program exits with an error?  If so, show us the error.  Do you mean it produces incorrect results?  If so, show us the results and explain what you wanted indread.

@Samwise: Probably not, at least on CPython; beyond string interning, all characters in the latin-1 range (ordinals 0 through 255) are singletons as an implementation detail (this isn't a guarantee of any kind and should not be relied on, and it's possible some code paths might accidentally make separate copies, but probably not in this simple case). So it probably works for the likely ASCII-only inputs the OP is likely using, but would break the moment they entered characters with ordinals of 256 or higher.

@Samwise: ...or not. x = 'a', x is x.lower() returns False in a simple interpreter check, so yep, it's the problem. x = 'a', y = input() (and entering a), then testing x is y is True, but x is y.lower() is False, so apparently even no-op .lower() calls are returning a new object that is not checked to collapse to the single character singleton.

Sounds like literals are interned, but not runtime values.
